# sqlite support for relationship between tables in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

It's my first time using sqlite to create a database instead of coredata. I have implemented everything fine but i don't have any idea how to implement relationships between tables. Does sqlite support relations in iOS at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; this relationship manifests as Foreign Keys and [the sqlite3 website](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) has extensive documentation on the subject.

Comment: for example 

CREATE TABLE Race
(
  RowId INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  RaceName   TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Citizen 
(
  RowId BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  CitizenName  TEXT,
  RaceId INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(RaceId) REFERENCES Race(RowId)
);

Comment: @Satya Great! but how do i implement this in objective-c? What methods are there inside libsql.h for this purpose?

Comment: @jim It's a C-API, not Objective-C.  If you want an Objective-C interface then look at FMDB.

Comment: This will help you http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application

Comment: @Droppy yeah i meant the C-API. Do i have to look up in the Foreign Key IDs of each table? That means i have to have two queries instead of one query.